# How does Google Hangouts works

Tags: webrtc, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

could someone share any links where described how Google Hangouts works under the hood? I've googled a lot about it and no answer. I know that they lately started to use WebRTC. Interesting about does it use WebRTC gateway? How there peers connected? Is there any mesh network of peers? How they managed to support up to 25 users in video call? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

https://webrtchacks.com/hangout-analysis-philipp-hancke/ shows a mid-2014 analysis. This is not using a mesh but a server.

Comment: Hello, thanks, yes, yesterday I've read this blog, looking for anything else. Any links highly appreciated